# SQL select multiple rows of data then compare

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

What would be the best approach in SQL Server 2008 to select something that ***can contain 10 list of data***, then compare that data with a specific value in one of it's columns

So something like this below

```
SELECT bType FROM WORK_STATION WHERE nFileId = 123456789
```

Which could return either 1 - 10 values MAX (will return at least one value). Then to compare the data from that SQL statement above that we just selected to a specific value to something like

```
if bType = 1
--DO something
```

What is the best approach of doing something like this?

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @table as table(btype int)
declare @btype int

insert into @table
SELECT bType FROM WORK_STATION WHERE nFileId = 123456789

while(exists(select top 1 'x' from @table)) --as long as @table contains records continue
begin
   select top 1 @btype = btype from @table

   if(@btype = 10)
     print 'something'

   delete top (1) from @table --remove the previously processed row. also ensures no infinite loop
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use SP to declare variables and then compare it with the resultset, if you know that you have only 10 values you can use temp table and insert 10 values.

I hope this is helpful.